# Postgres complicated full outer join keeping nulls from the "on" column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have written a PostgresSQL query that is relatively performant at scale and gives me the dataset I want back, but I am wondering if it is the simplest/best way to write the query. It seems like there should be a simpler join operation that satisfies the conditions I need.

**EDIT:** I do need this to be performant on large tables. In the example given below, pets is 150 million rows, food is roughly 100k rows. My solution at the bottom clocks in at about 0.6ms. Both tables have an index on id and user_id. The food table also includes an index on pet_id.

I have two tables that are related in my system that have one guaranteed shared attribute - the user_id. Here is an example that in essence shows my problem:

**Pets**

```
+------+-------+---------+
|  id  | type  | user_id |
+------+-------+---------+
| 1234 | dog   |       1 |
| 1235 | cat   |       1 |
| 1236 | gecko |       1 |
+------+-------+---------+
```

**Food**

```
+------+-----------+---------+--------+
|  id  |   name    | user_id | pet_id |
+------+-----------+---------+--------+
| 4321 | hamburger |       1 | NULL   |
| 4322 | dog food  |       1 | 1234   |
| 4323 | cat food  |       1 | 1235   |
+------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

**Desired Results**

```
+------+------+
| p.id | f.id |
+------+------+
| NULL | 4321 |  --no pet, hamburger
| 1234 | 4322 |  --dog, dog food
| 1235 | 4323 |  --cat, cat food
| 1236 | NULL |  --gecko, no food
+------+------+
```

Now with an example to refer to, I'll make sure it's clear what the result is. The result contains all rows from both sides that belong to my user_id (imagine that the table could contain thousands of other rows that don't belong to user_id 1). I want these result rows to include exactly ONE copy of each row matched to the other table.

An example of a full outer join that I tried to make this work:

```
SELECT p.id, f.id
FROM pets p FULL OUTER JOIN food f ON p.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE p.user_id = 1;
```

There's a bit of a problem in this query because

1. It excludes `NULL`s from the left side of the query. I need those.
2. Because the user_id is essentially the constant here, I end up with plenty of duplicates because it matches on user_id. Every row from the left gets matched to every row from the right. Not what I need. I need a one-to-one match.

I could fix #1 by including an `OR` in the `WHERE` filter:

```
SELECT p.id, f.id
FROM pets p FULL OUTER JOIN food f ON p.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE p.user_id = 1 OR f.user_id = 1;
```

For reasons I'm not completely sure of, it makes the query take a very long time. In our system, both tables have an index on user_id, so it isn't the lack of an index.

To solve my issue, I landed on the following query (really two combined):

```
SELECT p.id, f.id
    FROM pets p LEFT JOIN food f
        ON p.id = f.pet_id AND f.user_id = 1
    WHERE p.user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT p.id, f.id FROM pets p RIGHT JOIN food f
        ON p.id = f.pet_id
    WHERE f.user_id = 1 AND p.id IS NULL;
```

So my question is this: Is there a simpler way to execute this as a single query?

Comment: Did you try both query separatly? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I did try both queries separately. They run a bit more quickly (~0.3ms combined compared to 0.6ms for the union). I am attempting to have a dataset return to my application that saves me post processing/stitching of the data. I've edited the question just a little at the top to include a note about table size and current time performance. Desired performance would be similar to current. Just wondering if I was missing a more straightforward approach that performed the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/831f0/4)**

```
SELECT p.id, f.id
FROM pets p 
FULL OUTER JOIN food f 
  ON p.user_id = f.user_id
 AND p.id = f.pet_id
 AND p.user_id = 1;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|     id |     id |
|--------|--------|
|   1234 |   4322 |
|   1235 |   4323 |
|   1236 | (null) |
| (null) |   4321 |
```

**NOTE:**

You should add a composite index on `(user_id, pet_id)` for both tables.

Comment: You need a composite index on `(user_id, pet_id)` for both tables.

Comment: I think this best answers my question with this index comment included. Mind moving the comment into your answer and then I'll upvote and mark as accepted?

Comment: done the thing is if I leave a comment you get a notification. If I just edit the answer you dont. So how fast is now?

Answer (score 2):

You're just overthinking this a bit.  You want to join on `P.ID = F.PET_ID`:

```
SELECT P.ID, F.ID
FROM PETS P
FULL OUTER JOIN FOOD F ON P.ID = F.PET_ID
                      AND P.USER_ID = F.USER_ID
                      AND P.USER_ID = 1 --optional                          
ORDER BY P.ID
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Unfortunately, this is a bit slow at my scale. I've edited the question to be more clear on this. I attempted this query, and it took 122057 ms (a sequential scan happened on both tables).

Comment: @JustinR. See Juan's comment below - a composite index should speed things up